# How defined/Pass external form variable in user task?

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I defined process have user task this task contain external form i building this form using Form builder,
Where should be defined variable ? or add property in **form fields** or in ? where the mapping should be ?
and how can submit form ?[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"I defined process have user task this task contain external form i building this form"*? It seems incomprehensible. Can you revise it (by editing your question, not by responding in comments (if appropriate))? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the external forms as show in the below image:

[image]

```
embedded:app:forms/file_name.html
```

Sample form:

```
<!-- file_name.html -->
<form role="form" name="formName">
   <h1>Form Title</h1>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName-field">Name :</label>
      <input required cam-variable-name="userName" cam-variable-type="String" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password-field">Password :</label>
       <input required type="password" cam-variable-name="password" cam-variable-type="String" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</form>
```